# What beasts have the lowest Con, Wis, and Cha saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, ability-scores, animals

Suppose you have a target you absolutely need to fail a particular saving throw, and you've gotten a *wand of polymorph* to help improve your odds. Examples:

- a single dose of an expensive poison or a single spell slot for the *flesh to stone* spell (Con save);
- a *dominate monster* spell (Wis save);
- an *imprisonment* spell (Cha save);

or any other save with a long, lingering effect that will outlast the 1 hour duration of *polymorph*.

Most ordinary beasts have very low Intelligence scores, but what beasts have the worst ability scores for Constitution/Wisdom/Charisma saves like the above, and have the highest odds of failing those saving throws?

Comment: Why would you want to burn your dominate monster spell on a single  quipper or frog? I mean its interesting for curiosity reasons to know which beasts have low scores but the in-game motivation for this seems somewhat far-fetched.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin I think the idea is you have a high value non-beast target, then you use polymorph to turn it _into_ a beast (as required by the spell) with a bad save for your domination spell which persists after the polymorph ends.

Comment: @Kirt I get that, but polymorph itself requires a Wis save, so if your goal is to make it easier to succeed on a Wis save, that ploy is utterly useless.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin except if your source of polymorph is less expensive than the save you're trying to improve. If you have plenty of ways to polymorph a foe but a single use for the powerful save effect, it makes sense to "burn" your inexpensive spells until you get the best odds for your one-time ace. Also that's much more cinematic, but I'm always biased towards those kinds of strategies.

Answer (score 5):

### Constitution

Beasts are a healthy lot with an all-natural diet, there's no Constitution modifier lower than -1.

#### Constitution 8 beasts

- bat
- frog
- hawk
- owl
- raven
- scorpion
- sea horse
- spider
- weasel

#### Constitution 9 beasts

- quipper
- rat

### Wisdom

Only four beasts have a -2 Wisdom modifier.

#### Wisdom 7 beasts

- giant boar
- giant centipede
- giant fire beetle
- quipper

#### Wisdom 8 beasts

- camel
- crab
- frog
- lizard
- scorpion

#### Wisdom 9 beasts

- boar
- giant crab
- giant scorpion
- pteranodon

### Charisma

There are plenty of Intelligence 1 beasts, but there are no Charisma 1 beasts. Oozes like the gelatinous cube have Charisma 1, but even a spider needs to somehow secure a mate for sexual reproduction.

#### Charisma 2 beasts

- crab
- quipper
- scorpion
- sea horse
- spider

#### Charisma 3 beasts

- constrictor snake
- frog
- giant centipede
- giant constrictor snake
- giant crab
- giant fire beetle
- giant frog
- giant poisonous snake
- giant scorpion
- giant toad
- giant wasp
- lizard
- poisonous snake
- weasel

## Only the quipper is at the bottom of all tiers

The quipper has -1 to Con saves, -2 to Wis saves, and -4 to Cha saves. (The more traditional *frog* is only two out of three - it has a -1 Wis modifier.) A quipper can 'hold its breath' - so to speak - outside of water for 30 seconds, and drops to 0 hp 1 round after that, which ends the polymorph spell, so put it in a fish bowl long enough to do whatever you need to.

Quippers, frogs, and any other beasts with Charisma 3 or lower literally can't meet a spell save DC of 17 against the *imprisonment* spell, effectively guaranteeing the caster will succeed.